# Will Yarn consider the lock files of dependencies?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have an internal scaffolding application, for which I have created a `yarn.lock` file. Now, this application will be used by other Node applications. Will Yarn consider the lock file of its dependencies while installing dependencies for the main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, the answer would be **no**.

But there *is* a way around. If you see [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/711) discussion, there is a suggestion provided that uses

```
yarn add file:path-to-submodule
```

This is in my opinion, a more deterministic approach to handling submodule packages. So what you can do is this:

```
mkdir module && cd module
yarn init
mkdir submodule && cd submodule
yarn init                // Name this package 'submodule'
yarn add express         // Just an example package
rm -rf node_modules      // To see if node_modules is going to be regenerated
ls                       // package.json yarn.lock
cd ..
yarn init
yarn add react           // Another sample module
yarn add file:submodule  // Adds submodule as a local dependency
yarn 
cd node_modules && ls    // Both react & express and their dependencies are now in module/node_modules
cd .. && cd submodule && ls // No node_modules created within /submodules
```

Here you see that you have successfully created a local submodule within your main module, using `yarn add`

Advantage of using this method are:

- Only one copy of each package is saved
- All packages are in one location (only one node_modules folder)
- You can choose what packages are submodules and what aren't, so no surprises
- No secret submodules added to your package, just by virtue of their location within your package folder